# Rails error: "can't quote array"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm trying to add in a column in my users table which logs information about the user in an array stored in the database. Every time, I try to run this migration I made:

```
class AddLoggingToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :session_log, :string, array: true, default: [:username, :ip, :time, :user_agent]
  end
end
```

I then get this error within the console:

```
  -- add_column(:users, :session_log, :string, {:array=>true, :default=>[:username, :ip, :time, :user_agent]})
    rails aborted!
    StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

    can't quote Array
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Found that the default option is causing the issue, any clarity to why that is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've set the attribute type as string initially, which is causing the confusion. Try

```
add_column :users, :session_log, :array, default: [:username, :ip, :time, :user_agent]
```